# Looking for a database for cellular tower and antenna locations in the united states

Tags: data-request

I'm looking for something besides the FCC ASR. I need something more complete that list all of these sites.

Answer (score 2):

I have not looked into these datasets. The FCC (fcc.gov) has datasets on antenna registrations and the locations of cell towers:

<s>http://wireless.fcc.gov/geographic/index.htm?job=licensing_database_extracts</s>

archive.org link: https://web.archive.org/web/20141015140708/http://wireless.fcc.gov:80/geographic/index.htm?job=licensing_database_extracts